# How can I change the label of an ElasticBeanstalk application version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I go to the "Application Versions" section of my ElasticBeanstalk console, I see all my previous EB CLI deployments listed with "app-`<date>`_`<time>`" in the "Version Label" column. I would like to be able to change these, so I can give some versions human-recognizable names and more easily keep track of how the application would be if I re-deployed that version. I don't see any options for editing versions on the console, and the [update-application-version](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/update-application-version.html) command appears to only take a version-label argument for specification, not input. Does anyone know a way to do what I'm proposing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently not possible to change the label of an existing Elastic Beanstalk version.

To give a version a meaningful label, give it a meaningful label at the time the version is uploaded.

You could download the existing version and re-upload it with the new label. After that, delete the old version.

Comment: This should not be consider the solution (this is old now) take a look to @Jamsheer Kandoth 's answer

Comment: @PaoloFalomo  Jamsheer's answer does not address the original question of changing the label of an existing version, which cannot be changed. Jamsheer's answer simply deploys a new version to an environment, it does not modify labels of existing versions.

Comment: yep my fault https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183256/how-can-i-change-the-label-of-an-elasticbeanstalk-application-version/35183470?noredirect=1#comment75919747_43512027

Answer (score 8):

If you want to just change the label , not from console its possible  ,

use below to deploy your application with your own label

```
eb deploy --label version_label environment_name
```

Ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html

Comment: Worked perfectly - this should be considered as real answer

Comment: This answer does not address the original question of how to modify the label of an existing version. This answer only deploys a new version, which is not what was originally asked.

Comment: oh crap! misunderstood the question - that's pretty obv impossible to do. It is like change the hash of a commit.